# C++ List Unique() Function

Tags: c++, list, unique, operator-keyword

The following errors are always been pointing to my List.

In my class file

```
Point3D operator==(const Point3D &p1) const;
```

In my .cpp file

```
bool operator==(Point3D &p1, Point3D &p2)
{
    if ( p1.getX() == p2.getX() && p1.getY() == p2.getY() && p1.getZ() == p2.getZ() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In my main file

```
//declaration
list<Point3D> l_3D;

l_3D.unique(); <-- the error point to this
```

Error message

```
..... In member function 'void std::list<_Tp,_Alloc>::unique() [with_Tp = Point3D,_Alloc = std:: allocator<Point3D>]:

Instantiated from here

error: could not convert 'Point3D::operator==(const Point3D&) const (((const Point3D&)((const Point3D*)__next. std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*[with_Tp = Point3D]())))' to 'bool'
```

To the kind souls out there, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, instead of `if (some_bool_expression) return true; else return false;`, it is more idiomatic to just have `return some_bool_expression;`

Comment: It always makes me shudder when people write 'if ( a ) return true; else return false;' instead of just 'return a;'. :-}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your declaration you return `Point3D`, which should be `bool`:

```
Point3D operator==(const Point3D &p1) const;
^^^^^^^
should be bool
```

The above looks like you declare the operator as a member-function, bet then you implement it as a free function. You have to decide which it is. If you use a member-function, change the implementation to:

```
bool Point3D::operator==(const Point3D &p2) const
{
    if ( getX() == p2.getX() && getY() == p2.getY() && getZ() == p2.getZ() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Or even better (as per @ibids comment):

```
bool Point3D::operator==(const Point3D &p2) const
{
    return (getX() == p2.getX() && getY() == p2.getY() && getZ() == p2.getZ());
}
```

Generally the signature of your definition should match the signature of your declaration.

Comment: Also, it's bad style to write `if (...) return true; else return false;`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
bool operator==(Point3D &p1, Point3D &p2)
{
    if ( p1.getX() == p2.getX() && p1.getY() == p2.getY() && p1.getZ() == p2.getZ() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

To this:

```
bool operator==(const Point3D &p1, const Point3D &p2)
{
    if ( p1.getX() == p2.getX() && p1.getY() == p2.getY() && p1.getZ() == p2.getZ() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: When using this method, you must write the declaration outside the class declaration in the header (like `class Point3D {}; extern bool operator==(const Point3D &, const Point3D &);`).

Answer (score 0):

In your class file (I assume you mean a header file), you declare `operator==` as returning `Point3D` when it should be returning `bool`.  Also, your `operator==` has a different number of arguments in your class (header?) file and your cpp file.